# Test Coverage .NetCore

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net, opencover

I was looking for a TestCoverage for .netCore Xunit.

I found OpenCover, but i have no sucess to execute the command to run it:

```
C:\Users\andre.silva\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Users\andre.silva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe" -targetargs:"--lib dotnet test" -output:coverage.xml -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]*"
```

> Error: Unable to resolve project

Does Anybody know if OpenCover can runwith .NETCore projects?

Tks guys

Comment: I improved my command to: `C:\Users\andre.silva\.nuget\packages\OpenCover\4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"test C:\github\API_AspNetCore\test\test.csproj" -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]*" -oldStyle`. the answer was **No results, this could be for a number of reasons...the most common reason is  missing PDBs**

Answer (score 2):

With the current released version you will need to use full pdbs for it to work.

Comment: Tks. I improved my command to: `C:\Users\andre.silva\.nuget\packages\OpenCover\4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"test C:\github\API_AspNetCore\test\test.csproj" -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]*" -oldStyle. Do you know how can i modify my command to work with full pdbs? tks so much...

Comment: I improved my command to: `C:\Users\andre.silva\.nuget\packages\OpenCover\4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"test C:\github\API_AspNetCore\test\test.csproj" -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]*" -oldStyle`. the answer was **No results, this could be for a number of reasons...the most common reason is  missing PDBs**

Comment: Just input <DebugType>Full</DebugType> in csproj file :) tks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I was running a command with a simple 'dotnet **test**' but i should use 'dotnet **xunit**'

Just goes to your root folder in test project and run:

`C:\Users\andre.silva\.nuget\packages\OpenCover\4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"xunit" -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]*" -oldStyle`

Tks Guys

Comment: This means you are using xUnit.net 2.3 (instead of 2.2).